# Lampp Linux: how to enable MSQL accessable via network (ip / not only localhost)

Tags: mysql, xampp, lamp

i just update my lampp on centos 7. I've been setup the security using command ./lampp security

then i notice that i disable the MSQL for accessable via network, i actually want the mysql accesable via network. How to enable that again?

```
XAMPP:  Quick security check...
XAMPP:  MySQL is not accessable via network. Good.
XAMPP:  MySQL has a root passwort set. Fine! :)
XAMPP:  ProFTPD has a new FTP password. Great!
```

Comment: This is a server or database administration question, not a programming problem.

Comment: this is database administration

Comment: So why didn't you post on dba.stackexchange.com?